# Find g(y) and b so that $\int_0^2 (\int_{x^3}^{4x}\sin y^2\space dy)\space dx=\int_0^b\sin y^2g(y)\space dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, problem-solving

This came from a Calculus II exam:

Find $b$ and $g(y)$ so that:
$$\int_0^2 \left(\int_{x^3}^{4x}\sin y^2\space dy\right)\space dx=\int_0^b\sin y^2g(y)\space dy$$

I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: you want us to solve your calculus exam?

Comment: This is last year's exam. I am not so shameless as to ask here for help during an actual exam...

Comment: Without actually doing the problem, I suspect that b = 8. Draw the region of integration and see if you can convince yourself that b = 8.

Comment: Well my comment was a shameless not smart proof. Who wanting to solve its exam would said it so expresivelly?

Comment: The integral on the left can be evaluated by switching the order of integration. Perhaps this will give some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D=\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq 2, x^3\leq y\leq 4x\}$ we have
$$ \iint_{D} \sin(y^2)\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{8}\sin(y^2)\cdot\left(\sqrt[3]{y}-\frac{y}{4}\right) \,dy $$
by Fubini's theorem, hence a solution is given by $b=8$ and $g(y)=\sqrt[3]{y}-\frac{y}{4}$.

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

You just have to describe the region between two curves in two different ways, as $f_1(x)\leq y\leq f_2(x)$ or as $g_1(y)\leq x \leq g_2(y)$. The region between $y=4x$ and $y=x^3$ on the interval $x\in[0,2]$ is a normal domain with respect to both the $x$ and the $y$ variable.

Answer (score -1):

Formally, this is an underconstrained problem, You was wanting to seek for a value and for a function at the same time for giving an specific value, and there are infinitely many solutions.

A not so trivial guessing will be $b=7.19=\text{fresnels}^{-1}(0.46)$ and $g(y)=1$.

Comment: It's pretty clear on the paper that I must give them a number b and a function g(y). Wouldn't infinitely many solutions be a very unpractical thing for an exam question?

Comment: I'd bet there is an 'obvious' solution if you exchange the order of integrals.

Comment: Of course, totally out of the fairy rules for an exam. And i bet too there is a simple solution for a fresnel sine integral. Maybe carrying a CAS solver to the exam?. I guess the teacher put you a catch on a classroom tip. Did you attend all classes.

Comment: Yes, I can solve this with mathematica but that's not the point. I'm more interested in the solving process than the answer. I am going with @AlfredYerger 's suggestion and see where I get right now.